# Show active tab[bootstrap] from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the active tab from jquery or javascript.

```
<ul class="tab-group">
  <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#c">C</a></li> 
</ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="t1">text1</div>
  <div id="t2">text2</div>
  <div id="t3">text3</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do something like this but without success:
`$('.tab-group a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');`

where `tab` can be one of the above tabs: `a,b or c`.

Comment: So what is the specific problem? Please provide a runnable [mcve]

Comment: That does not seem like a bootstrap tab, where are the `nav` classes?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am not an expert with front-end tools, but I guess that you know what I want to do. Yes, I was wrong, this class is not from bootstrap but I was able to reproduce the above problem with nav nav-tabs from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think  that you need something like that

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> The class `active` is  responsible for making the tabs show.

Source, documentation and tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)

Comment: Is possible to user class="tab-group" instead of class="nav nav-tabs" ?
I want to use this class only for his design.

Comment: if "tab-group" does not conflict with "nav nav-tabs" I think you could add it correctly, but the class is mandatory if you want it to be in tabs . Add it to the question so we can see it all  @pcCC28